# Apply proguard log stripping to some classes only

Tags: android, logging, proguard

I'm using:

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static int d(...);
    public static int v(...);
}
```

to strip debug and verbose logging in an Android project.

I need to apply this logic to some files (everything under /somepackage) but not all of the app. Anybody knows how can this be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't apply this option selectively, but you can either create logging methods that delegate to the Log class, and then remove those, or you can add a final static boolean DEBUG flag before the logging statements and set it to false for your release.